# Space before three dots?

Tags: writing-style, ellipses, software, typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the proper way of using triple dots and spaces before/after them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26240/what-is-the-proper-way-of-using-triple-dots-and-spaces-before-after-them)

Should there be a space before three dots?

Examples:

> I don't know if this is good...
>
> I don't know if this is good ...

Also, as a status message intended for a software user:

```
Writing results... Done.
```

or

```
Writing results ... Done.
```

Comment: Related, but not necessarily great answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80948/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26240/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2811/2085  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37916/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/81492/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31390/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5972/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60707/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28175/2085